# Android C/S using ObjectInputStream and ObjectOutputStream with a Serializable class

Tags: java, android, sockets, classnotfoundexception, objectinputstream

On the desktop I have a perfectly working multithreaded client/server project using using ObjectInputStream/ ObjectOutputStream and a class that implements Serializable called Protocolo. This class is used on the server and on the client. As a learning experience I decided to implement the client on Android Studio. I created the following AsyncTasks:

OpenSocket – `OpenSocket extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Socket>`

OpenObjectInputStream – `OpenObjectInputStream extends AsyncTask<Socket, Integer, ObjectInputStream>`

OpenObjectOutputStream – `OpenObjectOutputStream extends AsyncTask<Socket, Integer, ObjectOutputStream>`

ReadFromServer - `ReadFromServer extends AsyncTask<ObjectInputStream, Integer, Object>`

WriteToServer - `WriteToServer extends AsyncTask<ObjectOutputStream, Integer, Boolean>`

On my MainActivity I have a method for the Connect button:

```
    public void ligarBtClick(View v) {
    String[] params = new String[]{
            server.getText().toString(),
            port.getText().toString()
    };
    AsyncTask<String, Integer, Socket> openSocket = new OpenSocket().execute(params);
    try {
        socket = openSocket.get();
        if (socket != null) {
            AsyncTask<Socket, Integer, ObjectOutputStream> openObjectOutputStream = new OpenObjectOutputStream(xChange).execute(socket);
            output = openObjectOutputStream.get();
            AsyncTask<Socket, Integer, ObjectInputStream> openObjectInputStream = new OpenObjectInputStream(xChange).execute(socket);
            input = openObjectInputStream.get();
            AsyncTask<ObjectInputStream, Integer, Object> readFromServer = new ReadFromServer(xChange).execute(input);
            msgFromServer = (Protocolo) readFromServer.get();
            fromServer.append("SERVER:\t" + msgFromServer.getType() + ": " + msgFromServer.getMessage() + "\n");
            toServer.requestFocus();
            desligarBt.setEnabled(true);
            ligarBt.setEnabled(false);
            enviarBt.setEnabled(true);
        } else {
            fromServer.append("LOG:\tCould not connect to " + params[0] + ":" + params[1] + "\n");
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I am connecting successfully, I am getting an input and an output stream and, using Wireshark, I can see that the server is sending a greeting to the client which the clients ACKs. The relevant part from the ReadFromServer AsyncTask is:

```
    @Override
protected Object doInBackground(ObjectInputStream... params) {
    Object msgFromServer = null;
    Message msg = Message.obtain();
    try {
        msgFromServer = params[0].readObject();
        msg.what = 5;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        msg.what = 6;
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    xchange.sendMessage(msg);
    return msgFromServer;
}
```

My app is crashing when I run ReadFromServer, more specifically when it hits this line `msgFromServer = params[0].readObject();` it will crash with the following messages:

```
06-20 12:34:08.745 12591-13006/pt.enta.jdm.tcpclientobject W/System.err: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Protocolo
06-20 12:34:08.745 12591-13006/pt.enta.jdm.tcpclientobject W/System.err:     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
06-20 12:34:08.745 12591-13006/pt.enta.jdm.tcpclientobject W/System.err:     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:251)
06-20 12:34:08.745 12591-13006/pt.enta.jdm.tcpclientobject W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ObjectInputStream.java:2265)
06-20 12:34:08.745 12591-13006/pt.enta.jdm.tcpclientobject W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1641)
06-20 12:34:08.745 12591-13006/pt.enta.jdm.tcpclientobject W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:657)
06-20 12:34:08.745 12591-13006/pt.enta.jdm.tcpclientobject W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1784)
06-20 12:34:08.745 12591-13006/pt.enta.jdm.tcpclientobject W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:761)
06-20 12:34:08.745 12591-13006/pt.enta.jdm.tcpclientobject W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1985)
06-20 12:34:08.745 12591-13006/pt.enta.jdm.tcpclientobject W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1942)
06-20 12:34:08.745 12591-13006/pt.enta.jdm.tcpclientobject W/System.err:     at pt.enta.jdm.tcpclientobject.ReadFromServer.doInBackground(ReadFromServer.java:30)
06-20 12:34:08.745 12591-13006/pt.enta.jdm.tcpclientobject W/System.err:     at pt.enta.jdm.tcpclientobject.ReadFromServer.doInBackground(ReadFromServer.java:14)
06-20 12:34:08.745 12591-13006/pt.enta.jdm.tcpclientobject W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
06-20 12:34:08.745 12591-13006/pt.enta.jdm.tcpclientobject W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
06-20 12:34:08.745 12591-13006/pt.enta.jdm.tcpclientobject W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
06-20 12:34:08.755 12591-13006/pt.enta.jdm.tcpclientobject W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
06-20 12:34:08.755 12591-13006/pt.enta.jdm.tcpclientobject W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
06-20 12:34:08.755 12591-13006/pt.enta.jdm.tcpclientobject W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
06-20 12:34:08.755 12591-13006/pt.enta.jdm.tcpclientobject W/System.err: Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Protocolo
06-20 12:34:08.755 12591-13006/pt.enta.jdm.tcpclientobject W/System.err:    ... 17 more
06-20 12:34:08.755 12591-13006/pt.enta.jdm.tcpclientobject W/System.err: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "Protocolo" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/pt.enta.jdm.tcpclientobject-6.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/pt.enta.jdm.tcpclientobject-6, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
06-20 12:34:08.755 12591-13006/pt.enta.jdm.tcpclientobject W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
06-20 12:34:08.755 12591-13006/pt.enta.jdm.tcpclientobject W/System.err:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
06-20 12:34:08.755 12591-13006/pt.enta.jdm.tcpclientobject W/System.err:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
06-20 12:34:08.755 12591-13006/pt.enta.jdm.tcpclientobject W/System.err:    ... 17 more
06-20 12:34:08.755 12591-12591/pt.enta.jdm.tcpclientobject D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
06-20 12:34:08.755 12591-12591/pt.enta.jdm.tcpclientobject W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41f79bc0)
06-20 12:34:08.755 12591-12591/pt.enta.jdm.tcpclientobject E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                             Process: pt.enta.jdm.tcpclientobject, PID: 12591
                                                                             java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4508)
                                                                                 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18675)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5584)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
                                                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                              Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4508) 
                                                                                 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18675) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5584) 
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084) 
                                                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                              Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                 at pt.enta.jdm.tcpclientobject.MainActivity.ligarBtClick(MainActivity.java:66)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
                                                                                 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4508) 
                                                                                 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18675) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5584) 
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084) 
                                                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The class it is complaining about is the class that exists in the server (not in the client); I changed the name of the class in the server and sure enough it complained it could not find the new name. Can't figure this one out.

Thanks!

Comment: The class has to exist at both the sender and the receiver.

Comment: It does exist both on the server and on the client. otherwise it would not compile. This is a runtime error.

Comment: It doesn't exist at both the server and the client **at runtime.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution to my own problem. The class Protocolo is used by both the server and the client. The class **has to be in the same package** both in the client and in the server. I had the class in the client and in the server but (and as far as I am concerned this would be normal) in different packages.

Thank you!

Comment: Exactly as I stated. It doesn't exist at both the server and the client. Two classes with the same name in two different packages are two different classes, not the same class.

Comment: I agree! I wish you had been more detailed in your initial answer. In any case, thank you.